# Git 443 Error when try to push origin master? Why github turns githum? what should I do?

Tags: git, push, github-for-windows

Unable to access 'https://**githum**.com/loveohno13/learning.git/':

> Failed to connect to **githum**.com port 443: Connection refused

I've retried for many times but it didn't work.
I don't know why it says cannot connect githum which should be githum
What could I do to fix it?

[image: Error info]

Comment: This looks like it could be an SSL problem.  Have any configuration settings (e.g. keys, certificates) changed recently?

Comment: use git from a shell and look at `git remote -v`.  Perhaps you missed typed a string.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your projects root directory, open the file `.git/config`. Inside there will be the address of the github repository. Change all references from `githum.com` to `github.com`.

You could also just try running the command from your root project directory assuming your environment has the `sed` command installed.

```
sed -i "s#githum.com#github.com#g" .git/config
```

Answer (score 0):

A silly typo, that's all to it :-)

```
githum instead of github
```

Comment: Yup, silly typo^^   just didn't know how to correct it, Got it now. thanks!